# Send email on new strapi entry with Flutter

Tags: flutter, email, mobile, push-notification, strapi

I have a flutter app that uses strapi to get some images (only GET requests). I want that if an user selects "Yes, I want notifications sent to my email" notifications be sent to their email.

For example, let's say I have an "email" collection in strapi. Each time a new collection is added, my flutter apps gets notified of this and sends an email to all the users suscribed with the information of the new entry. How can I do that?

Or maybe I can do all of this in strapi without having to touch my flutter app at all?

Comment: You do that via lifecycles https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/models#lifecycle-hooks

Comment: To receive updates in app you need sockets https://github.com/ComfortablyCoding/strapi-plugin-io

Comment: Or you have to poll endpoint